# How to set multiple clients and channels in Supabase Realtime

Tags: node.js, websocket, supabase, supabase-js, supabase-realtime

I coded a simple app that connects to one supabase client and leverages the `postgres_extension` to listen for chnages of a particular table. This is a simple nodejs application like the one shown in the docs here: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/realtime

Question - and maybe this is not a supabase specific question but rather a `websocket/Phoenix/Elixir` question.
Can I instantiate multiple supabase clients in the same `nodejs` application each subscribing to its own topics? sort of like listening to multiple "rooms" at the same time from within the same app.. Multiple supabase client is a requirement (as the events would come from different supabase accounts).

Is this possible? is it only a matter of just instantiating another client and listen for events?

```
supabase_new_client
  .channel('new_channel')
  .on('postgres_changes', { event: 'INSERT', schema: 'public', table: 'todos' }, handleInserts)
  .subscribe()
```

Wonder what sort of perf issues will I encounter on the machine where this is deployed?

As a follow up, are there any best practices for how to handle if a connection is lost or something went wrong with the channel connection? So that I can restart it for example?

Comment: In addition, what sort of monitoring/logging can I leverage from the supabase_client object? is there a way I can know if a connection is closed for example?

My main  concern is understanding how many client websocket connections I can establish (I'm guessing that depends on the VM itself) 
and what can i do if I detect that something failed (how to detect that essentially)